# MDI Windows and passing accelerators between a parent and a child window issue

Tags: c#, mdi

I have MDI application with the menu strip and one child window.
The child window uses accelerators (& sign before enu item name)
When left alt + other key pressed MDI parent's menu strip gets activated and child window is not able to use accelerators.

I have to have a menu strip within the parent window but want to disable accelerators for it.

Is there any way to do it?

Regards
Mariusz

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails to achieve this you could always take the Accelerator messages from the main window and pass them to the focused child window.  You could use the WndProcs to do this.  Its more of a hack, but you might not be able to get past the capturing of the main menu of the accelerator pressing.  Try looking at these [Example1](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/article.php/c4639),[Example2](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-D/dislog/tutorials/article.php/c4965)